# Get last old order status before updated status in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I'm currently looking for a way to get the order status before an updated order status.

---

So for example my order has the status `in-progress` and I change the order status programmatically with this function here to `wc-completed`:

```
$order->update_status( 'wc-completed' );
```

When the order status is `wc-completed` I've a trigger which sends an email. But I need to check now if the status before the current one was `in-progress`. If this is true, I need to skip the trigger:

```
$latest_status = get_order_status_before_current_one($order_id);
if ($latest_status !== 'in-progress') {
    // Triggers for this email.
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1, 2 );
}
```

How can I reach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that **before updating** the order status with `$order->update_status( 'wc-completed' );`, you will need to add a kind of status history on each status change event, using the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'grab_order_old_status', 10, 4 );
function grab_order_old_status( $order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order ) {
    if ( $order->get_meta('_old_status') ) {
        // Grab order status before it's updated
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_old_status', $status_from );
    } else {
        // Starting status in Woocommerce (empty history)
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_old_status', 'pending' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE** - Then now you can use one of the following IF statements *(with the Order ID)*:

```
if( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_old_status', true ) !== 'in-progress' ) { 
    // Your code
}
```

Or *(with the Order Object)*:

```
if( $order->get_meta('_old_status') !== 'in-progress' ) { 
    // Your code
}
```