# Disabling increase stock for specific order status changes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

Currently when the order status changes to `cancelled` the stock of the products is increased.

I would like to disable the stock increase when the new status is `cancelled` but **only for some previous order status** *(not all)*.

For example, when the status changes:

- From `processing` to `cancelled`: Do not increase stock
- From `shipped` to `cancelled`: Do not increase stock
- From `other-status` to `cancelled`: Increase the stock
- From `cancelled` to `processing`: Decrease the stock

So far I have tried this:

- [Disabling Auto Restocking for Cancelled Orders](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disabling-auto-restocking-for-cancelled-orders/)
- [Get last old order status before updated status in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347823/get-last-old-order-status-before-updated-status-in-woocommerce)
- [Reduce stock only for specific order statuses and payment method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863990/reduce-stock-only-for-specific-order-statuses-and-payment-method-in-woocommerce)

I tried `remove_action` with the `wc_increase_stock_levels` function but it's not working for me. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: HI @Jen, could you add the code snippets that you used from the various links and where you added them to your question. It would allow us to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get the previous order status when updating the product stock. This is because the `wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels` function triggers with the [**`woocommerce_order_status_cancelled`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.363) hook that is executed before the hooks:

- [`woocommerce_order_status_' . $status_transition['from'] . '_to_' . $status_transition['to']`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.372)
- [`woocommerce_order_status_changed`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.373)

*From these hooks you could have obtained the previous and new order status*.

You can get around this in two steps:

1. Disable the stock increase for the **cancelled** status *(regardless of what the previous order status was)*
2. Set the stock increase **based on one or more previous order statuses**

In case you want to enable the stock increase only for orders that change the status from "other-status" *(custom)* to "cancelled", you can use the following code:

> Replace `other-status` with the previous order status slug *(without the
> **wc-** prefix)*.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_stock_increase' );
function custom_stock_increase() {
    // disable stock increase when order status changes to "canceled"
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
    // enable stock increase when status changes from "other-status" to "canceled"
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_other-status_to_cancelled', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels' );
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*